# Access: Search box for Greater than Less than

Tags: sql, ms-access, inequality

Is there a way to setup a query parameter to take a user input from a form to find a number that is greater than one number and less than another but still have it be okay to be blank if the user doesn't enter anything?

I tried `Like "*" & Between [Forms]![DeptControl]![FastTime] And [Forms]![DeptControl]![SlowTime] & "*"`

But that kicked out as an error and it won't let me do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't combine `Like` and `Between` into one condition like that.

It sounds like you just want to check whether some number is between `[FastTime]` and `[SlowTime]`.  If so, leave `Like` out of it:

```sql
[Your Number] Between [Forms]![DeptControl]![FastTime] And [Forms]![DeptControl]![SlowTime]
```

And if you want to return all rows when either `[FastTime]` or `[SlowTime]` is Null, add those conditions with `OR`:

```sql
[Your Number] Between [Forms]![DeptControl]![FastTime] And [Forms]![DeptControl]![SlowTime]
OR [Forms]![DeptControl]![FastTime] Is Null OR [Forms]![DeptControl]![SlowTime] Is Null
```

Comment: Well, I would ideally like it to able to be greater than one thing or less than another and not necessarily be a "between" statement.  Could I just tack on something like a OR <[FastTime] OR >[SlowTime]?

Comment: Would that allow just FastTime or SlowTime to be null while the other isn't while still accounting for it needing to be less than if FastTime is filled in or greater than if SlowTime is filled in?

Comment: No, I misunderstood.  `[Your Number] > [Forms]![DeptControl]![SlowTime] OR [Your Number] < [Forms]![DeptControl]![FastTime] OR [Forms]![DeptControl]![FastTime] Is Null OR [Forms]![DeptControl]![SlowTime] Is Null`

Comment: Is there any way to work a "between" statement in there as well so that if the user puts values in both, they can get values between the two?  And THANK YOU so much for the help thus far!  I'm in a MUCH better position than I was.

Comment: Please add a matrix to your question to show us what you want returned from each combination of Null and not Null in `FastTime` and `SlowTime`

Comment: Basically it can be between the two, Less Than FastTime, Greater Than SlowTime, or either/both be Null.  I apologize for not knowing how to add a matrix to the reply.  :(

Comment: You told Darren that the times are "speed in seconds".  So if `FastTime` is 7 and `SlowTime` is Null, you want the query to return all rows whose `[Your Number]` value is less that 7? (You said " Less Than FastTime".)

Comment: Solved it, had to add AND statements in combination to each of the Is Null's and also put a another combination statement of using AND between two Is Null's (one for fast and one for slow).

Comment: HansUp, yes.  FastTime is what I have as the time that it would be faster than, thus actually less than b/c quicker is less than in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use NZ:  `NZ([Forms]![DeptControl]![FastTime],NOW())` - if left NULL it will use the current time.

Comment: Time in this case is actually speed in seconds, not date/time.  TY though!

Comment: Just replace the NOW() part with the default value you're after.